# heroku rack:cache .. vs Amazon S3 + Amazon Cloudfront

Tags: caching, heroku, amazon-s3, rack, amazon-cloudfront

Using this reference about Heroku Cedar,

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31#rackcache-storage

They recommend using a combination of rack:cache (as entity store) and memcache (as meta store) .. The actual files are stored in the entity store, I believe..

In the guide above they set it to "file:tmp/cache/rack/body"..

Say I want to store static html files in cache and have them expire in 7 days.. Am I better off by using the above rack:cache + memcached combo or would I be better off by just storing all my html files in Amazon S3 + Cloudfront CDN and then running a cron job to delete all html files from my S3 bucket to ensure fresh html pages every seven days.

the logic would be as follows:

If user requests a particular html file from S3 and it does not exist .. my app generates a new html file in S3 and we wait until the next S3 Mass-delete operation via cron.

Files are only generated if users "request for them"... I have about 5 million static files that need to be at most a week old.. I do not want my S3 bucket to fill up with 5 million HTML files unless my visitors are requesting all 5 million html files every week... I estimate they will request only about 10k unique files a week or so..

So my question here is.. which would be more efficient and faster? Storing all my html files in rack:cache entitystore.... with memcache acting as metastore....... OR to run with Amazon S3 + Cloudfront?

I'm looking for 2 angles here:

1. Which is better for reducing total time to get to user?
2. Which is better for reducing the load on my webserver?

The solution might address both issues.

Comment: What did you decide to do here?  I have a similar use case....

Comment: I havent implemented the app yet.. but I am looking at a way to store all the files in S3 backed by CloudFront CDN. The cache invalidation and dynamic generation of content in S3 is the tricky part that I still have to figure out.